# How detect common elements from two lists?

Tags: r, list

I have two lists. And I want to attribute 1/4 for each common value for each line of them.
This is an example:

```
v=c(433,405,451)
v1=c(405,416,388 ,464,392,393,433)

w=c(405,385,384,431)
w1=c(405,478,451,430)

list1=list(v,v1)
list2=list(w,w1)

> list1
[[1]]
[1] 433 405 451

[[2]]
[1] 405 416 388 464 392 393 433

> list2
[[1]]
[1] 405 385 384 431

[[2]]
[1] 405 478 451 430
```

The fact, we see common values which are 405 in the first and second line of both list, we create then a vector including 1/4 if there is a common value and 0 if not:
In this case, the ouput value should be like this:

```
 1/4
 1/4
```

This is because list1[1] and list2[1] have 405 as common value.
and list1[2] and list2[1] have 405 as common value.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: I modified the code! It's more easier now!

Comment: You're still posting `head` when you should be posting the results of `dput` - don't make others manually type in and recreate your lists.

Comment: @Mark, It's done!

Comment: @lmed How do you get the table you want as output?

Comment: @R18 you are right, i change it into vector it's more correct.you can see that 405 is a common value between the first element of list1 and list2 . So we get 1/4 . The same for the next line (405 is common value between the second line of boths lists)

Comment: Yes, but your table presents 8 elements and you have only 2 list with 2 vectors each one. I want to understand the names of rows and columns of your final table.

Comment: @R18, I modified this table into vector! Just admit if there is just one common value between each line of both lists. for example,the first line of the vector has 1/4 value.(because 405 is in list1[1] and in list2[1]).the same for next line!

Comment: Maybe `length(intersect(list1[[1]], list2[[1]]))` is what you are looking for; this will have a value `> 0` if there are common elements.

Comment: @pentandrous, Thanks very much !! great Idea!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sapply(1:length(list1),function(x){if(sum(list1[[x]] %in% list2[[x]])>0){1/4}else{0} })
```

gives

```
[1] 0.25 0.25
```

And should work as long as your two list are of same length

Answer (score 1):

I would use ifelse for this task

```
ifelse(v %in% v1,1/4,0)
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.00
```

Comment: I just reinvented a wonderful function. Thanks for your answer